# Java HttpClient get response from Post method

Tags: java, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am new to HttpClient and I'm trying to get the prices of players in the fifa ultimate team web app.

Using Developer Tools, i managed to find the Post Method yielding the prices of the player.

Searching for a specific player gives the following URL request.
https://utas.s2.fut.ea.com/ut/game/fifa15/transfermarket?maskedDefId=20801&start=0&num=16&type=player

When I'm viewing the response of the method, I can see all the player prices currently on the market in Developer Tools.

So I tried to code it in Java to get those prices, but my output is nothing like the response given in Developer Tools.

This is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String url = "https://utas.s2.fut.ea.com/ut/game/fifa15/transfermarket?maskedDefId=20801&start=0&num=16&type=player";
        HttpPost loginPost = new HttpPost(url);
        loginPost.setHeader("Host", "utas.s2.fut.ea.com");
        loginPost.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
        loginPost.setHeader("Content-Lenght", "1");
        loginPost.setHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        loginPost.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
        loginPost.setHeader("Origin", "https://www.easports.com");
        loginPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36");
        loginPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        loginPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        loginPost.setHeader("X-UT-SID", "23c19a93-32ac-4f52-9aab-21c6be112ede");
        loginPost.setHeader("X-UT-Embed-Error", "true");
        loginPost.setHeader("X-UT-PHISHING-TOKEN", "8649502695209937021");
        loginPost.setHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "GET");
        loginPost.setHeader("Referer", "https://www.easports.com/iframe/fut15/bundles/futweb/web/flash/FifaUltimateTeam.swf?cl=144469");
        loginPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate");
        loginPost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "nl-NL,nl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
        loginPost.setHeader("Cookie", "CEM-Rememberlogin=mRLLf4Ua9QJAz1J1va8yrhwlh9jFEaLsccY1Q3Ja7wREWecJnF3H348jrRpTnr3qXnhX-YKV6TH3HWgEPqgExDUP2vMFeiwkAYSkhyMuJUyHF_Fsou-fiv7Ur2XVYpqVo1KEP_dO0lLaJ5zTV1I8paWera57lPKmWxY5KzOdnRTGBbpbBv2bJOVPlGLpUFWmbOdMxElcTQga7S2-nM3icZc0JQQ2gmtDCKJ48VHSTl3x3BEuT3ltfNvFEt8elFIf; Path=/");
List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("maskedDefId", "20801"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("num", "16"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start", "0"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "player"));
        loginPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(loginPost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String content = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        System.out.println(content);
```

This is the response Developer Tools is showing and what I need:

`{"auctionInfo":[{"itemData":{"id":164674417976,"timestamp":1412181858,"itemType":"player","pile":5,"resourceId":1929400641,"rating":93,"leagueId":0, etc}]}}`

This is my response:
`?[][][][][][][][]?V?M-.NLOU??+???Q*JM,??S?RJ?(?,JMQ([]?[]G[]Et???S??L[][]k[]??[]?6[][][]`
where `[]` stands for the unknown character (square)

So my question is: How do I adjust the code such that I will get the response of the requested URL?
Any help would be appreciated

Edit:
All I had to do was to delete some 'setted' headers:
Those are the 'setted' headers I still need:

`loginPost.setHeader("Host", "utas.s2.fut.ea.com");
        loginPost.setHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36");
        loginPost.setHeader("X-UT-SID", "23c19a93-32ac-4f52-9aab-21c6be112ede");
        loginPost.setHeader("X-UT-Embed-Error", "true");
        loginPost.setHeader("X-UT-PHISHING-TOKEN", "8649502695209937021");
        loginPost.setHeader("X-HTTP-Method-Override", "GET");`

But here, the values of "X-UT-SID" and "X-UT-PHISHING-TOKEN" are not correct, they are not the actual values (since I copied them from a previous session). How should I fix my code in order to get the actual value?

Thanks in advance

Comment: so what is the response you are getting when you run your code? The response you're saying is so different from developer tools

Comment: what makes you think you need a `POST`? And why do you put the same parameters in the query and in the body?

Comment: While searching on the transfer market in the web app, I have to press the button "search"  which makes a post-request (stated in Developer Tools). Since I'm simulating the post-request, I'm adding all parameters I find in the post-request stated in Developer Tools (I'll add the image)

Answer (score 0):

Is there some documentation? Maybe you have to set manually the encoding, like:

```
loginPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

maybe change "utf-8" with other charset (like 'iso-8859-1')

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. I have two possibilities in mind why the code doesn't return the right output: Maybe I have to set the cookies myself (in the code, I simply copied the cookies stated in developer tools) or I have to add code to change from JsonObject to a JavaObject since "entity" is now in Json (as the response of the server is Json)